# Do averaged binary symmetric channels maximize mutual information?

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory, entropy

This is a refined version of  [Do binary symmetric channels maximize mutual information?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213084/do-binary-symmetric-channels-maximize-mutual-information), which was answered negatively.

Let the random variables $(X, Y)$ be a doubly symmetric binary source with parameter $0 \le p \le 1/2$, i.e., $X,Y \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ and $P(X \neq Y) = p$.

Define the two regions $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$:

- $\mathcal{A}$ consists of all points $(R_0, R_1, R_2)$ such that there exist **binary** random variables $U,V$, satisfying the Markov chain $U - X - Y - V$ and
  \begin{align}
   R_1 &\ge \mathrm{I}(U;X) , \\
      R_2 &\ge \mathrm{I}(Y;V) , \\
      R_0 &\le \mathrm{I}(U;V) ,
  \end{align}
  where $\mathrm{I}(\cdot;\cdot)$ is mutual information.
- $\mathcal{B}$ consists of all points $(R_0, R_1, R_2)$ such that there exist probabilities $a,b \in [0,1]$ with
  \begin{align}
   R_1 &\ge 1 - \mathrm{H}(a * p) , \\
      R_2 &\ge 1 - \mathrm{H}(b * p) , \\
      R_0 &\le 1 - \mathrm{H}(a * p *b) ,
  \end{align}
  where $a*b := a(1-b)+(1-a)b$ is binary convolution and $\mathrm{H}()$ is the binary entropy function.

My Question: Is $\mathrm{conv}(\mathcal A) = \mathrm{conv}(\mathcal B)$, where $\mathrm{conv}()$ denotes the convex hull?

Some comments:
The definitions of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are almost the same, except that the channels $X \to U$ and $Y \to V$ are required to be symmetric for $\mathcal{B}$ and hence $\mathcal B \subseteq \mathcal A$.
The question [Do binary symmetric channels maximize mutual information?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213084/do-binary-symmetric-channels-maximize-mutual-information) asked whether $\mathcal A = \mathcal B$ and a counterexample was provided for $p=0$, which does not seem to apply here.